# Theming node add form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I want to theme this page node/add/classified. 
I tried creating page--node--add.tpl.php, page--classified--add.tpl.php, page--node--classified--add.tpl.php refreshing cache all the time...Nothing works

I tried also implementing hook_theme() and hook_preprocess_page().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a tpl file for a particular content type as you mentioned in your post "node/add/classified", then I would suggest, you should go with the tpl name like this

*Drupal 6* : **page-node-add-[content type].tpl.php**

*Drupal 7* : **page--node--add--[content type].tpl.php**

in your case, this would be (*assuming your Drupal version is 7.x*):

**page--node--add--classified.tpl.php**

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thnx that is correct, but since my "Node add" was using another theme (administration theme) I had to put that file in the admin theme

Comment: for that scenario, you can copy your admin theme to your "sites/all/theme" folder, select that theme as your admin theme and put this .tpl file in that theme folder.